# Stage in the Screen or Game class?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, stage, scene2d

I'm new to Scene2d, so i'm a little confused. Imagine that we have this two classes:

```
public GameScreen implements Screen {

//override methods
}

public GameX extends Game {

//override methods
}
```

both methods have methods like render and resize, so my question is:

Which of both is the best approach to include Stage/actors and Box2d stuff?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you have a simple game, you can just put everything in Game. If you want to break up your game into separate  Screens, then you can put that stuff in a Screen, and use the Game class to switch between them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the answer! I just wanted that feedback to continue the coding

Comment: It does matter so that you are clear about things. The "Game" allows you to attach different Screens. Go for this approach. Your derived Screen classes eg LoadingScreen, GoodbyeScreen etc etc can then encapsulate the screen specific logi. See Game::setScreen . All will become clear. The Stage class is used to contain your actors. You can define the spritebatch and viewport used when setting up your Stage : e.g hudStage = new Stage(hudViewport, hudSpriteBatch);

Answer (score 0):

The `Game` class is actually the core of the game. It's methods are called by the `GameLoop` or, if some events occure.
Every game can have multiple `Screen`s, like for example the `MenuScreen`, the `PlayScreen`, the `OptionScreen` or the `CreditsScreen`.
So a `Screen` repressents something like a part of a game.
The `Game` class can have one active `Screen` at a time and it calls `reder()` for that `Screen` in it's own render. The same counts for `pause()` and `resume()`.
If you change the active `Screen`, `hide()` gets called for the old `Screen` and `show()` for the new `Screen`.

So the answer to your question is, that if your `Game` is really simple and does not contain different `Screen`s, you can put the `Stage` inside the `Game` classs and treat the `Game` class like your one and only `Screen`.
If you instead have more then one `Screen` you should use the `Screen` interface and setup the `Stage` in one of the `Screen` clases.

Answer (score 0):

I use both since the Game class can switch between screens `setScreen`. Usually I first load a `loadingScreen` that loads needed assets when loading is done i switch to a `mainMenuScreen`. But you can put some actors in the game class and load screen implementations from there, it really does not matter.

But for a clean approach I advice to just call a loading screen from the `Game` `create` method and build from there. Since each game needs at least some kind of menu and a game screen itself.